# What is grouping?

Tags: c

In the introduction to K&R there is the following text:

> Similarly, C offers only straightforward, single-thread control flow:
>   tests, loops, grouping, and subprograms, but not multiprogramming,
>   parallel operations, synchronization, or coroutines.

What does `grouping` refer to? It is not in the index, and searches have been unfruitful so far. I've programmed some C (though I'm far from an expert), and haven't heard the term before.

Comment: My guess is structs.

Comment: @whatsisname I don't think so, as it's referring to control flow, not data structures.

Comment: FYI K&R is *ancient* compared to the current C standard, it's only useful these days as a historical guide

Comment: @ratchetfreak I disagree. The second edition is still the best published C book ever. It is a compact book that demonstrates how to write modular ANSI C code. Are there really so many changes between ANSI C and and C11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"C program source text is free-format, using the semicolon as a statement terminator and curly braces for grouping blocks of statements." (Wikipedia)

Blocks don't look like control flow, but they are; without the curly braces only the next line would be controlled by a loop keyword, but with the braces the entire block is looped over.